# Display popup of sculpt brush in a pie menu

Tags: python, scripting, pie-menu

Is it possible to display directly the sculpt brush popup using a pie menu?
If I add the `template_ID_preview` in the pie menu I have to click on it to display the popup, but it's not exactly what I want.